# R assign levels to factor variable

Tags: r, categorical-data

I was given an Excel table similar to this:

```
datos <- data.frame(op= 1:4, var1= c(4, 2, 3, 2))
```

Now, there are other tables with the keys to `op` and `var1`, which happen to be categorical variables. Suppose that after loading them, they become:

```
set.seed(1)
op <- paste("op",c(1:4),sep="")
var1 <- sample(LETTERS, 19, replace= FALSE)
```

As you can see, there are unused levels in the data frame. I want to replace the numbers for the proper associated levels. This is what I've tried:

```
datos[] <- lapply(datos, factor)
levels(datos$op) <- op
levels(datos$var1) <- var1
```

This fails, because it reorders the factors alphabetically and gives a wrong output. I then tried:

```
datos$var1 <- factor(datos$var1, levels= var1, ordered= TRUE)
```

but this puts everything in `datos$var1` as `NA` (I guess that's because of unmatching lengths.

What would be the rigth way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the expected output but perhaps you want `datos$var1 <- factor(var1[datos$var1], levels = unique(var1))`?

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: Great, perhaps you can write up an answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the kind advice of @docendoDiscimus, I post this answer for future reference:

For the data provided in the question:

```
datos$var1 <- factor(var1[datos$var1], levels= unique(var1))
datos
## op
```

Please notice that this solution should be applied **without** converting `datos$var1` to factor (that is, without applying the code `datos[] <- lapply(datos, factor)`.